# How does Rubocop statically check for ruby syntax errors

Tags: ruby, rubocop

How does [Rubocop](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop) statically check for ruby syntax errors? Since Ruby is a dynamic language, if you don't use Rubocop then will you only be notified of syntax errors during runtime? I.e. when your run your program it will crash due to a syntax error?

Comment: Could you elaborate what the question is? Do you want to know how Rubocop parses Ruby code (and can detect syntax errors) without actually running the code, or do you want to find syntax errors without Rubocop, or is it something else you want to know?

Comment: I'm curious as to how Rubocop parses Ruby code (and can detect syntax errors) without actually running the code.

Comment: Parsing and running code are two different things, although they typically happen after each other for interpreted code. While it isn't its main topic, [this article](http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/2/29/the-joke-is-on-us-how-ruby-1-9-supports-the-goto-statement) I read the other day explains quite nicely how Ruby is parsed.

You can also browse the [RuboCop source](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop) on GitHub to try to find the parser code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not even need a tool like Rubocop. Ruby itself is able to check the syntax without executing the code:

```
$ ruby --help
Usage: ruby [switches] [--] [programfile] [arguments]
[...]
-c              check syntax only
[...]
```

Let's check if it finds syntax error:

```
$ ruby -c -e "def; end"
-e:1: syntax error, unexpected ';'
```

Ruby reads and parses the source code first and executes in a later step. If the first step of parsing already fails because the code doesn't make any sense then executing would be impossible anyway. It is not the execution that finds syntax errors it is the parsing of the code.

But there are of course errors which Ruby doesn't find but other programming languages would detect when compiling the code. For example a `TypeError`:

```
$ ruby -c -e "[1,2][:bar]"
Syntax OK
```

The syntax is fine but does this code actually work?

```
$ ruby -e "[1,2][:bar]"
Traceback (most recent call last):
-e:1:in `<main>': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
```

Comment: "IMHO it is obvious that a check like this must be possible." – That is not obvious at all. E.g. Perl5 cannot be parsed statically, it must be executed in order to be parsed. Perl6 has dynamic syntax, the syntax of the language can be modified at runtime. Many Lisps have reader macros, and at least those reader macros need to be executed during parse time.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That is interesting. I never looked into this in details, but without thinking too much about it, I would have thought that all programming languages would work one step after the other. I charged the wording in my answer...

Comment: thanks @spickermann! As a minor correction, I think you mean "executing would be impossible anyway" instead of "executing would not be impossible anyway"?

Answer (score 0):

RuboCop uses the [parser](https://github.com/whitequark/parser) gem. The gem provides some diagnostics information when it encounters syntax errors while parsing. RuboCop simply re-packages the parsing error inside the [Lint/Syntax](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/blob/master/lib/rubocop/cop/lint/syntax.rb) cop, and uses the diagnostics information to create a RuboCop offense with a nice error message.