# How to validate schema.rb file in rails for any syntax errors?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, schema

We have two different apps and both are dependent on each other's database for running the tests.

For example, we create `App2`'s DB before running the specs in `App1` using the `App2` - `schema.rb`.

The issue here is that there have been a few scenarios where we faced syntax issues like `Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax;` while creating the `App2` SQL structure in `App1`'s test using the `schema.rb`.

So, I was thinking is there any way to verify the `schema.rb` in `App2` after someone has updated it? So that we never face any issues while creating the structure in `App1`.

Comment: _"both are dependent on each other's database for running the tests"_ – that sounds like an anti-pattern. The apps would probably be easier to maintain if each could run its test on its own. Maybe you could move the "cross-app" tests into a separate integration test suite which then runs both apps together.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your `schema.rb` contains *only* Ruby code and not raw SQL, you can likely safely validate it with Rubocop:

```bash
rubocop db/schema.rb
```

Alternatively, [you can use `ruby`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56096853/3784008) to do the same:

```bash
ruby -c db/schema.rb
```

However two things in your post indicate to me that you may have raw SQL:

1. The error `Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax`
2. The quote "the App2 SQL structure" which may indicate that you're actually [dumping the SQL structure](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-the-sql-schema-dumper)

If you have raw SQL then you may want to consider a SQL linter like [sqlfluff](https://sqlfluff.com/) which can do the same thing that Rubocop does but for raw SQL:

```bash
sqlfluff lint db/structure.sql
```

Alternatively, you can integrate a step in your test suite that deletes and recreates the test database using the schema to ensure that when the test suite runs it validates the schema:

```bash
bundle exec rails db:drop db:create db:schema:load db:migrate
```

You can run this in one or both of the apps' test suites to ensure that the schema is working as expected.

Finally, you should ensure that changes to the schema are only ever made through ActiveRecord migrations; don't edit the schema file directly and ensure that it only updates via migrations.

---

**Additional advice based on the comments conversation below**

If your schema is even slightly complex or includes *any* raw SQL or Arel commands then use [the SQL schema dump option](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-the-sql-schema-dumper) instead to generate raw SQL:

> When the schema format is set to `:sql`, the database structure will be dumped using a tool specific to the database into `db/structure.sql`. For example, for PostgreSQL, the `pg_dump` utility is used. For MySQL and MariaDB, this file will contain the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the various tables.

This will mean that your schema is managed in `db/structure.sql` instead of `db/schema.rb` going forward.

First, add this to `config/application.rb`:

```rb
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

Next, dump your schema using the following command:

```bash
bundle exec rails db:schema:dump
```

As described above, you can load this schema using:

```bash
bundle exec rails db:schema:load
```

Comment: Valuating schema.rb with Rubocop won't actually accomplish that much as its generated by the schema dumper and is thus probably syntactically correct ruby if it hasn't been tampered with.

Comment: It can also be syntactically correct Ruby but still generate invalid SQL as there are many methods in the DSL that take strings (the index option is a common culprit). The Ruby schema dumper is a very leaky abstraction and does tend to fail at dumping the schema as soon as you're doing anything vaguely complex

Comment: @max I've not encountered that problem before so I'm curious if you can provide more insight. If the migrations are written in pure Ruby and the schema is only ever altered by migrations, would the successful completion of the migrations always result in a safely dumped schema, or can a successful migration result in a live database state that dumps to an invalid schema? Talking about only pure Ruby, nothing using raw SQL and nothing using Arel.

Comment: Hmm, I know I have encountered questions here where it happens but I can't think of one of the top of my head. In theory at least the schema dumper should be able to parse the limited subset of SQL that can be generated with the migrations DSL alone - but edge cases can occur. Usually its not really that the schema dumps to an invalid schema - rather the issue is fidelity. Anything it doesn't grok just goes lost in translation which leads to sneaky issues that are only discovered when you recreate the db from the schema.

Comment: Makes sense to me, I've seen lost-in-translation issues a handful of times but truly can't remember the context. I think what you're saying is that the Rails code to dump the schema isn't perfect and probably never will be given that it tries to be database-agnostic, and I agree that that's an important consideration for OP's question and my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I would generally say that the Ruby schema dumper works well enough for simple use cases but if you're actually concerned about the integrity of the schema it's better to use SQL dumps.